# How to reduce audio file size

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have a recorder to record Microphone but i'm getting high file size, I would like to reduce the size with high quality file.

Here is the recording settings: **This settings works and i can play the audio but it has high size.**

```
AVFormatIDKey:NSNumber(value: kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
AVEncoderBitRateKey : 12000,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
AVSampleRateKey : 44100
```

I have tried to use `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` With this i'm always gettings 28b of size, But i couldn't get it to play there is an error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)

Could someone please explain what is going on or how can i get high quality with lowest size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because of the wrong file format or other URL problem. Just change it accordingly. E.g you can remove `AVFormatIDKey` parameter and use `.caf` file extension.

Comment: with `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` it will be m4a file format? I tried what you said ".caf" 16sec = 2.7MB is this normal or should i make low settings because i feel its take time to upload on firebase

Comment: @Salah no, the extension is `.aac`. And it really proves to show the best results in terms of memory taken.